# Android 8 and IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, crash-reports, android-8.0-oreo

When reviewing the crash reports of my application I've noticed a sudden spike now that Android 8 is out. The backtraces in the Google Play console only points to java code that's out of my reach. Could it be that there's a problem within Android 8 or do I need to update something in my app to make it compatible? Where in my code should I look first?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3645)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3685)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1643)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
    at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:437)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1610)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState (FragmentManager.java:3035)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume (FragmentManager.java:3001)
    at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume (FragmentController.java:200)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:7100)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3620)
```

*Update*

After some debugging it seems to be the exact same problem as in this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37131681

Comment: check for on resume method of the Activity

Comment: Have you run your app on v 8?  You can run an emulator if you don't have a device.

Comment: @nasch No, that was totally off my radar because of previous bad experiences with the emulator. Will try it now though. Thanks!